# What's wrong with my double integral for determining the area of an ellipse?

Tags: integration

It is parameterized as follows: $x = 2\cos(\theta)$ and $y = 3\sin(\theta)$.

This is my double integral. It is not evaluating to the right answer. Why?

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\sqrt{4\cos^2(\theta) + 9\sin^2(\theta)}} dr\,d\theta$$

I remember from calculus 3 that to get the area for polar coordinates, I just evaluate $dr$ and $d\theta$. I don't see what's wrong with the limits of integration. The radius is from 0 to the formula and the radians are a full revolution.

Comment: The area element in polar coordinates is $r \, dr \, d\theta$.

Comment: ahh i see sorry my mistake

Comment: Worse, there is a serious problem. The $\theta$ that appears in this parametrization is NOT the polar coordinates $\theta$. You can see this quite easily if you think about stretching a circle to make the ellipse.

Comment: The corrected integral is giving me $13\pi/2$, and computing the area using Green's theorem is giving me the correct $6\pi$. Is there still a mistake here?

Comment: Yes, @JacobAustin, see the comment I just posted.

Comment: The area of an ellipse of major axis $2a$ and minor axis $2b$ is certainly $\pi ab$.

Comment: Of course. So our parameterization of the space is $x=2r\cos\theta$ and $y=3r\sin\theta$, and the Jacobian is $6r$, so the integral is just

$$6\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1r\,dr\,d\theta=6\pi$$

Alternatively, of course, we could use a $u=x/a$, $v=y/b$ transformation, or just use Green's theorem.

Comment: @JaconAustin, it's already parameterized. Why did you parameterize it again using r? Doesn't r = 1 if you throw it in there?

Comment: @TedShifrin could you explain a bit more how theta is not the polar coordinates theta? I don't see how stretching a circle to make an ellipse explains it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to include a diagram, I'm turning my comment into an answer. As I said, the $\theta$ that appears in this parametrization is NOT the polar coordinates $\theta$. You can see this quite easily if you think about stretching a circle to make the ellipse. I've substituted $t$ in the parametrization and indicated the polar coordinates $\theta$ as well.

[image: Ellipse]

To do this integral *correctly* in polar coordinates you must get the polar coordinates equation of the ellipse for starters: 
$$\frac{x^2}4 + \frac{y^2}9 = 1 \implies \frac{(r\cos\theta)^2}4 + \frac{(r\sin\theta)^2}9 = 1 \implies r = \frac1{\sqrt{\frac{\cos^2\theta}4+\frac{\sin^2\theta}9}}.$$
Ugh! This will give us the integral
$$\frac12\int_0^{2\pi} \frac1{\frac{\cos^2\theta}4+\frac{\sin^2\theta}9}\,d\theta,$$ which can be done, but this is *not* the right way to do this problem!

Comment: Thank you for the figure. However, how is the fact that the thetas don't equal each other when the x1=x2 a problem? It is an ellipse, but that should be taken into consideration from the limit of integration of this particular integral that I wrote in my question-$\int_0^{\sqrt(4*cos...)}dr$ The radius limit is not constant, thus the radius changes based on the formula.

Comment: And then the theta tells it how far to traverse. The ellipse is still 2pi radians

Comment: Also, the constants 2 and 3 stretch out the x and y coordinate respectively. Since you drew the line to the ellipse at a different y coordinate so it is not proportional to the original circle of 2/1 x and 3/1 y, so of course the degrees aren't the same, but I don't understand the relation between evaluating the area.

Comment: When you compute the area by doing $$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{r(\theta)} r\,dr\,d\theta,$$ the function $r(\theta)$ must actually be giving $r$ in terms of the *polar coordinate* $\theta$. That is wrong with your parametrization, as I've tried to explain. The vector to the point $(2\cos t,3\sin t)$ makes angle $\theta=\tan^{-1}\big(\frac32\tan t\big) \ne t$ with the positive $x$-axis.

Comment: I am beginning to understand, but I've thought about this for a while and I still have some intuitive questions. Say that I merely substitute $d\theta$ for $dt$. I know this is mathematically incorrect because of the formula you've given relating theta and t, but I don't see how this is wrong intuitively. I keep the upper limit of the integral at my mistaken $r(t)$ rather than $r(\theta)$. The radius is now expressed as t. Then, I traverse the full revolution of the circle with t rather than theta. The limits will be the same: from 0 to 2pi.

Comment: In this case, the only difference between theta and t will be the rate of change of the direction vector sweeped out, which I do not think is a problem. Is there something wrong with my reasoning?

Comment: You're wrong. It is a huge problem. You need a $d\theta/dt$ in the integrand now.  Note that the answer your get with your approach is definitely wrong, as @JacobAustin has already commented several times. By the way, I just worked it out: $d\theta/dt = 6/(4\cos^2t+9\sin^2t)$, so we're soon back to the integral I posted above. (Oops, not quite. It's a slightly different integral.)

Comment: You're saying that this: $\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{r(t)}r dr dt$ doesn't get the area? I don't understand why it doesn't and what you mean by needing $d\theta/dt$

Comment: No, you must have $r$ as a function of $\theta$ as the upper limit, as I put at the end of my response. If you're going to have $r(t)$, then you will need to have $d\theta = (d\theta/dt)dt$ to do the integral with respect to $t$.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but if I try to rederive the whole double integral again using dt rather than $d(\theta)$ I obtain what I just posted, and I don't see where the problem is.

Comment: With a $dt$ integral, it all works out rather nicely: Your $\int_0^{r(t)} r\,dr$ comes out $\frac12(4\cos^2t+9\sin^2t)$. We now have to integrate $$\frac12\int_0^{2\pi} (4\cos^2t+9\sin^2t)\frac{d\theta}{dt}dt = \frac12\int_0^{2\pi} (4\cos^2t+9\sin^2t) \frac6{4\cos^2t+9\sin^2t}\,dt = 3\int_0^{2\pi} dt = 6\pi,$$ which (hurrah!) is the correct answer.

Comment: As I said, first get the radius in terms of t. The radius sweeps out from the origin. Then the limits for t are from 0 to 2pi

Comment: This is my last word on the matter: You can't use $r\,dr\,dt$ for any old parameter $t$. You need *polar coordinates* $(r,\theta)$ in order to have $dA = r\,dr\,d\theta$. Otherwise, more generally, you need a Jacobian determinant that gives the appropriate "fudge factor." That's what I'm doing ad hoc when you replace $\theta$ with your parameter $t$.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand why the rate of grow of the angle affects the evaluation of the integral.

Comment: Review change of variables (integration by substitution) in single integrals? Is $\int_0^1 \sin(t^2)\,dt$ the same as $\int_0^1 \sin(u)\,du$ ($u=t^2$)?

Comment: It's hard to explain my question. What I am trying to say is that if I use a different axis with $t$ rather than $\theta$ and then I try to rederive the area using the technique shown in the first part of this website here: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/DIPolarCoords.aspx, I get that the $dA = r*dr*dt$. I appreciate your willingness to help me understand. I think I haven't been very clear with my question

Comment: Nope, that's wrong. You need to look up the general change of variables result and learn what a Jacobian is. Study what I've written instead of being so stubborn.

Comment: I know what they are and I'm not being stubborn. I'm just trying to understand it without blindly following formulas and not comprehending any of it.

Comment: @TedShifrin can you please see similar [question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3661447/fitting-an-ellipse-to-an-ink-drop-on-the-cloth-with-constraints) can be contributed to as well.